# SonarQube Unable to Start localhost

Tags: sonarqube

I'm having some trouble to start the sonar in Ubuntu box, even i could not trace the sonar log with more information.

sonar.logs

```
root@jenkins-linux-vm:/opt/sonar/logs# cat sonar.log 
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.12.24 13:16:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2019.12.24 13:16:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.12.24 13:16:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.12.24 13:16:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2019.12.24 13:16:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.12.24 13:16:24 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.12.24 13:16:29 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.12.24 13:16:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2019.12.24 13:16:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

java version

'''
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.5+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.118.04, mixed mode, sharing)
'''
can you please some one help me on this.

Comment: Did you start as a root user (that is not allowed)? Maybe [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu-16-04) can help you.

Comment: Hi Jeroem, I logged with root user only, But still its falling, do we need any DB required for this sonar scanner

Comment: Don't use a root user. The scanner does not need a database. With the correct scanner configuration the output is sent to SonarQube. SonarQube itself needs a database but if you don't specify one a database will be created for demo purposes. Don't use that database in production environments.

Comment: Ok got it, i will start the sonar.sh start with normal user, and i will update the result shortly, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, Now my sonar is working fine, thanks lot for your help